# Edit Classes From Github Libraries

Tags: android, github

I have installed the folder picker as per instructions from Github found on this link: `https://github.com/kashifo/android-folder-picker-library`

I have added the following line to gradle:
`implementation 'lib.kashif:folderpicker:2.4'`

And added to MainActivty:

`import lib.folderpicker.FolderPicker;`

And in onCreate:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityFolder.this, FolderPicker.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Everything works fine accept that this type of installation seems to be working 'online' as I don't understand where this class is: `FolderPicker.class`, I would like to make changes to it and its xml layout (remove the New button etc..), how can I edit this library and customize it instead of using it as it is?

I have also downloaded the entire package as well and it also doesn't have all classes and layouts located within the app folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking in to wrong folder , The app folder is for the sample project . The actual library will be in folder with name [folderpicker](https://github.com/kashifo/android-folder-picker-library/tree/master/folderpicker)

Here is the link to the class [FolderPicker.java](https://github.com/kashifo/android-folder-picker-library/blob/master/folderpicker/src/main/java/lib/folderpicker/FolderPicker.java) .

If you want to customize the library then clone the project , edit the parts you want in folderpicker and include the the folderpicker module to your project  Or generate an aar file and add aar file in the project . If you have time you can even publish on jcentre/maven and directly include it as a gradle dependency

Answer (score 0):

Follow This Steps For Import Module and Edit Libraries class in Android Studio.

1. First Download Project From Github Then Go to Android Studio-> File -> New ->                       Import Module...
2. Select the source directory of the Module you want to import and click Finish.
3. Open Project Structure and open Module Settings for your project.
   `Open the Dependencies tab.`
   `Click the (+) icon and select Module Dependency. Select the module and click Ok.`
   `Open your build.gradle file and check that the module is now listed under dependencies.`(implementation project(path:":YOUR_PROJECT_MODULE_NAME")